# How to make aggregation, using PHP MongoDB driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I use [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) MongoDb driver in my application. I like it, because it works well. I can run simple select and insert statements, like:

```
$em = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb");
$query = new Query(['name' => 'John']);
$res = $em->executeQuery('users', $query);
```

But the problem is, I can not find even a single example on making aggregations. PHP documentation does not say a word about this. While, MongoDb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#complex-queries-with-aggregation) seems to use another library:

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->test->restaurants;

$cursor = $collection->find([
    'name' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^' . preg_quote('(Library)')),
]);
```

It seems like an example from another library, because MongoDb driver does not have this `MongoDB\Client` class. There is such a class, but in a [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) library. So, what is the right way to make aggregations in PHP, using modern MongoDb driver?

Answer (score 1):

> This extension provides **a minimal API for core driver functionality**: commands, queries, writes, connection management, and BSON serialization.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

To execute `aggregate` command, use [MongoDB\Driver\Command](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-command.php)

```
{
  aggregate: "<collection>" || 1,
  pipeline: [ <stage>, <...> ],
  explain: <boolean>,
  allowDiskUse: <boolean>,
  cursor: <document>,
  maxTimeMS: <int>,
  bypassDocumentValidation: <boolean>,
  readConcern: <document>,
  collation: <document>,
  hint: <string or document>,
  comment: <string>,
  writeConcern: <document>
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#syntax